# MouseUp and MouseDown don't work on a child of usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, mouseup

I have an usercontrol and an ellipse inside it. I try to catch MouseUp event on the ellipse, but it doesn't work.

```
<UserControl ...>
  <Grid>
    <Rectangle x:Name="el" Fill="Black" MouseUp="Ellipse_MouseUp"/>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and here code behind

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
    {
        
        public MyControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }
        private void Ellipse_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            //some logic
        }

}
```

Comment: to be honest, looking at your code it doesn't seems to have any error. Please provide the entire code to let us investigate the issue

Comment: try adding "e.handled = true" in Ellipse_MouseUp.